# Turning HighChart into a stacked Bar Graph with Title

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, highcharts

I am new toHighCharts, and I am trying to turn my current HighChart into a stacked Bar Graph with a title and I am struggling to get the code to work. It is currently a normal bar graph with no title and I want to stack it.

```
function get_chart() {
    return {
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },

        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                stacking: 'normal',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white',
                    style: {
                        textShadow: '0 0 3px black'
                    }
                }
            },
            series: {
                cursor: 'pointer',
                point: {
                    events: {
                        click: function () {
                            alert('Category: ' + this.category + ', value: ' + this.y);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },

        series: [{
            type: 'column',
            name: 'Tweets',
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
        }, {
            type: '',
            name: 'Total',
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
            marker: {
                lineWidth: 2,
                lineColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[3],
                fillColor: 'white'
            }
        }]
    };
}

var app = angular.module('charts', []);

app.directive('highchart', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div></div>',
        replace: true,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            scope.$watch(attrs.chart, function () {

                if (!attrs.chart) return;

                var chart = scope.$eval(attrs.chart);

                angular.element(element).highcharts(chart);
            });

        }
    }
}]);

function Ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.example_chart = get_chart();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See below code, here is working [fiddle with your code](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/nqdapxgg/1/)

```
  plotOptions: {
        series: {
            stacking: 'normal',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white',
                style: {
                    textShadow: '0 0 3px black'
                }
            },  point: {
                events: {
                    click: function () {
                        alert('Category: ' + this.category + ', value: ' + this.y);
                    }
                }
            }
        } 

    },

    series: [{

        name: 'Tweets',
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }, {

        name: 'bar',
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
        marker: {
            lineWidth: 2,
            lineColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[3],
            fillColor: 'white'
        }
    }]
```

few points: you were drawing column chart,but actually wanted to have a bar chart. you were setting plotOption for column, instead I set stacking in plotOption.series.

Comment: After replacing my code for plotOptions with yours it has turned into a line graph. I think your missing the part that this is in an AngularJs Directive,

Comment: you have to use type:'bar' and it should work properly, in your angularjs function you are consuming chart object , just add chart{ type:'bar'} and then it should work properly. try it

Comment: or in series >>           series: [{
          type:'bar', //add this 
            name: 'Tweets',
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
        }

Comment: Your right! Thanks a lot! Also how do add the chart title and make it a vertical Stacked Bar Graph?

Comment: for vertical stacked chart >> just change the type to column . means type:'column' and for title title:{text:'your title'} see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/nqdapxgg/2/ @user2402107